# Android how to place all my classes in one package using Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I am developing SDK, my environment got SDK library and a testing project that use it.

I want to protect my library code from my library users and there for I need to obfuscate it, but just it.

So in Android Studio in my library Module, in proguard-rules.pro file I added the next script:

```
-dontpreverify
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic

-keep class !com.example.**{ *; }
-keep public class com.example.sdk.Example{*;}
-keep public class com.example.sdk.IExampleCallback{*;}
-keep public class com.example.sdk.ui.ExampleActivity

-dontwarn android.util.Log

-repackageclasses 'com.example.security'
-allowaccessmodification
```

The classes get obfuscated but their package is not changed. I fallowed [Eric Lafortune](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141319/i-am-using-repackageclasses-my-pdt-z-option-of-proguard-plugin-but-obfuscate)(The author of Proguard) suggestion to add `allowaccessmodification`, but it didn't helped. I also try using `flattenpackagehierarchy`, but it had no effect.

Help me, how to place all my classes in one package?

Comment: allowaccessmodification solved my problem, thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Solved it: After adding those lines it did the job

```
-useuniqueclassmembernames
-keeppackagenames doNotKeepAThing
```

This is my full script

```
-optimizationpasses 30
-mergeinterfacesaggressively
-dontpreverify
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic

-repackageclasses 'com.example'
-allowaccessmodification
-useuniqueclassmembernames
-keeppackagenames doNotKeepAThing

-keep class !com.example.**{ *; }
-keep public class com.sdk.example{
    *;
}
-keep public class com.sdk.IExampleCallback{
    *;
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames public class com.sdk.ui.activity.ExampleActivity{
    public <methods>;
    protected <methods>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames public class com.example.sdk.ExampleReciever{
    public <methods>;
}

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
```

Comment: This really helps a lot. Thanks.

Comment: 30 optimization passes? I think 5 is more than enough

Comment: @Inkognito from proguard manual: _If no improvements are found after an optimization pass, the optimization is ended_